# How to make a mesh deform accurately with smaller rigid bodies (rope animation)?

Tags: animation, physics, bezier-curves, rigid-body-simulation, parent

I am trying to achieve a physically realistic and visually realistic dynamic rope simulation for knot-tying and untying in 2.80.

So far, I have an animation using rigid body cylinders linked together with rigid body constraints and I am able to get the desired physical behavior and tie knots that handle self-collision by keyframing the cylinder locations:

[image: knot-sim]

The problem is that it does not look like a visually compelling rope, just like a bunch of cylinders with gaps in between. Does anyone know of a good solution to have a realistic looking rope mesh (i.e. something like this) deform the same way as this set of connected cylinders?:

[image: rope texture]

I know the above kind of rope can be made using a twisted mesh with a Bezier curve modifier, but this does not have the kind of realistic dynamic physical properties (like handling self-collision) for my use case.

Is there any way to parent the cylinders to the vertices of a separate mesh such that it follows the deformation? Or is there any way to "wrap" ALL the cylinders in a texture that will also deform with the rest of the rope? Or any other suggested solutions involving parenting/hooks/rigging?
Thank you *so* much!!

Comment: Look at the last two steps in the linked question. They transfer the cylinder motion onto a bezier curve.

Comment: Thank you so much @Leander! Super helpful and exactly what I was looking for